# Issue regarding Facebook login in Didn't find class LoginButton

Tags: android, facebook-login

Issue regarding fb Login

**Build.gladle**

```
        apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

        android {
            compileSdkVersion 23
            buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'

            dexOptions {
                incremental true
                javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
            }


            defaultConfig {
                applicationId "com.bindaspunch.my.bindaspunch"
                minSdkVersion 13
                targetSdkVersion 23
                multiDexEnabled true
                versionCode 1
                versionName "1.0"
            }
            buildTypes {
                release {
                    minifyEnabled false
                    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                }
            }
            sourceSets { main { res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/main/res/anim'] } }
        }

        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }


        dependencies {
            compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
            testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

            compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
            compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
              compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.1.0'
            compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.1.0'
            compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
             compile files('libs/volley.jar')
             compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.4.0'

        }
```

**My Xml**

```
             <com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
                        android:id="@+id/login_button"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />
```

I update my gradle.properties file with these lines

```
# org.gradle.parallel=true
ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION = 19
ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION = 19.1.0
ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION = 15
ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION = 19
```

**Exception:**

```
         Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.facebook.widget.LoginButton" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.bindaspunch.my.bindaspunch-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.bindaspunch.my.bindaspunch-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

My Sdk android studio version is 1.5.1

i have this issue till 30 hours

i have to use login with facebook in my android app but there was errors like failed to import file or facebook loginbutton class not found.

i m new in android and never use android studio much , i tried all the solution regarding facebook login , but nothing helping me out.

my sdk is updated to latest version too.

i m totlly frestrated from login with facebook

i tried allmost ever demo code there on many sites , but nothing is working properly , this is my new changed code and it have the issue of  facebook login button file not found.

anyone helping me regarding this issue... thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3):

replace

```
com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
```

with

```
com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
```